# systray gadget to start stop tomcat

Tags: tomcat, windows-services, applet, systray

I'd like to know if anybody knows of any systray applet to control tomcat service con windows xp...

apache installs its own, and there's one for mysql in the mysql gui tools...

so the only one I'm missing is tomcat...

thanks a lot

Comment: +1 because I don't get it why people rate this question down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomcat (from version 5.5 onwards at least) should come with a Monitor Tomcat option. It should be within the start menu for Tomcat. Add it to the start up programmes if you want it to start each time.

Some information is at:
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/windows-service-howto.html

The programme address is as follows for my machine (XP):

```
"C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 5.5\bin\tomcat5w.exe" //MS//Tomcat5
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been searching around and found the following

http://www.ghacks.net/2009/07/01/windows-services-manager/
http://winservicemanager.codeplex.com/releases/view/29648

Project Description
This software runs in the tray and you can select which services you want to control from the tray.

I tried it, and it seems to work as expected, so far...

also found the following, but didn't even bothered to try it

http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/OS-Enhancements/Mutliservice-Controller.shtml